# how to find working days and weekends in current month?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find how many working days and weekends in a current month. using **PHP** and **MySQL**.

I have try below code :-

```
  select 5 * (DATEDIFF('2017-02-28', '2017-02-01') DIV 7) +  
  MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400001234000123440', 8 * WEEKDAY('2017-02-01') + WEEKDAY('2017-02-28') + 1, 1) as workingdays
```

Please give solution to find working days and weekends ,

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Your method seems more robust than the accepted answer

Comment: By using this query showing me 19 working days. In a month of February actual working days are 20.

Comment: sir, can u give me a query for that. my above question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN WEEKDAY('2017-02-01') < 5 THEN 5 - WEEKDAY('2017-02-01') ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN WEEKDAY('2017-02-28') < 5 THEN WEEKDAY('2017-02-28') + 1 ELSE 5 END 
+
(DATEDIFF('2017-02-28', '2017-02-01') + 1 
- (7 - WEEKDAY('2017-02-01')) 
- (WEEKDAY('2017-02-28') + 1)
) DIV 7 * 5 AS working_days;
```

Assuming that start_date: 2017-02-01 and end_date is 2017-02-28

Comment: Thank you so much sir, using this query it shows me accurate working days in current months

Comment: @Mayur, try to mark the answer as valid,maybe it is useful for someone in the future.

Comment: I'm not convinced!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT  5 * (DATEDIFF('2017-01-31','2017-01-01') DIV 7) + MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400012345001234550', 7 * WEEKDAY('2017-01-01') + WEEKDAY('2017-01-31') + 1, 1)+1 workingDays FROM DUAL;
```

Hope it helps you.